# React-custom-scrollbar does not work with mouse click ( but works with mouse scroll ) on pages with height below 400px

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollbar

The website is made in React.

The problem is with react-custom-scrollbar. On pages, which height is higher than 400px, the scrollbar responds to mouse click. Nevertheless, on the pages with height below 400px, the scrollbar does not work after mouse click. In all pages the scrollbar code is the same as above:

```
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

 <Scrollbars
    autoHide
    renderTrackHorizontal={props => <div {...props} className="track-horizontal" style={{ display: 'none' }} />}
    renderThumbHorizontal={props => <div {...props} className="thumb-horizontal" style={{ display: 'none' }} />}
    autoHeight
    autoHeightMin={windowHeight}
  >

</Scrollbars>
```

The questions:
1. What am I missing in scrollbar code that it does not work on pages with small height?
2. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with **zIndex**, which was set to the main . It caused that the scrolllbar was below in the stepping order.

In this case, there were 2 solutions which worked:

1. Remove the zIndex in the main , if it was signed.
   or
2. Set the zIndex: 1001 for the scrollbar